# Deploy MS Access Runtime via group policy

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, deployment

I am trying to deploy Access 2007 runtime via group policy and I am having a problem. So, i downloaded the AccessRT.exe and run accessrt.exe /extract to get the msi file. Then when I try to attach the .msi to a software policy to the new gpo I get the following error.

"Add Operation Failed.
Unable to extract deployment information from the package. Run validation on
the package to ensure that the package is correct."

To the best of my googling ability I find that I need to create a config.xml file. Well, documentation isn't the best there and I still can't get it to work even after creating a config.xml file(below).

```
<Display Level="none" AcceptEula="yes" />  

<INSTALLLOCATION Value="%programfiles%\Microsoft Office" />

<LIS CACHEACTION="CacheOnly" />

<DistributionPoint Location="\\Shared\NETLogon\Software Deployments\Microsoft\Access RT 2007" />

<Logging Type="standard" Path="%temp%" Template="AccessRT(*).txt"/>

<Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="NEVER" />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have office 2000 installed on the computer you are trying to add this policy from? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my attempt to figure this out. I tried running the msi on my computer and recieved an error....

Error 1713. Setup cannot install one of the required products for Microsoft Office Access Runtime 2010

Which led me to this article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926279

So long story short, starting with Microsoft office 2007 you can't install any product via a .msi file.

Fail.

Thanks microsoft.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the previously accepted answer is just wrong I will post the correct one here.

Microsoft expects you to integrate Office into your Windows deployment image so they removed support for GPO-MSI deployment in order to integrate other features into the installer that are not supported in every MSI deployment situation. You expect everyone that has a need for automatic GPO deployment to have a KMS running so they can deploy standard images with all basic software in them. The need for Office GPO-deployment has vanished with Office 2000 as all later versions can receive their updates through WSUS and therefor can be imaged with the operating system without the need for periodic redeployments with slipstreamed servicepacks and updates.

For all those who don't use imaging systems or don't want to integrate Office into their OS deployment there ist still a way to deploy and to remove MS Office through GPO; it is just not the easy-clicky-way the modern Windows administrator has come to expect.

Read this blog as everything you need for automated deployment ist explained there in great detail:
[https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956190.aspx] [1]

If you want to be able to remove the product later on (for example if you want to roll out a later Office version without changing to a later OS version) you have to expand it by a little step.

Just create 2 GPOs, one of them gets the computer startup script for Office 2010 deployment you can find in the article mentioned above. The other one gets a slightly modified startup script that uninstalles Office if it is installed.

You can even put the GPOs onto the same OUs if you play a bit with their security settings:

- Create a security group, called somthing like "Office2010", that containes all computers that should get the product installed
- Add this group to the deployment-GPO and give it "Apply GPO"-rights
- Remove the "authenticated users" group's "Apply GPO"-rights, but leave its "Read"-rights in
- Add the "Office2010" group to the removal-GPO and give it the deny option of the "Apply GPO"-right. Leave the "Authenticated users" goup in this GPO with the standard rights.

That way every computer who is a member of the "Office 2010" group will execute the deployment script on startup and deploy Office 2010 if necessary. Any other computer will instead execute the removal script and uninstall Office 2010 if it is still installed.

[1]: Microsoft TechNet article "Geek of All Trades: Automatically Deploying Microsoft Office 2010 with Free Tools"

Comment: link provided is dead